# Xamarin ignoring my accents

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm building and iOS App using Xamarin Studio and having some problems with the accents. Seems that the file enconde is wrong or something like that, but I can't find where/how to fix it.

For example, assuming that label is an outlet to a UILabel on my storyboard:

```
label.Title = "Álbum";
```

is showing "Album" without the accent on the interface.

If I try to do an Insert into a SQLite database like this:

```
connection.ExecuteScalar<EventData>("Insert Into EventData (Id, Description, Kind) values ('1', 'Mamãe chegando.', 0)");
```

I get an error in the SQL. But the same SQL when used on a sqlite console runs without a problem.
And when I run this SQL without the "ã", works even on the Xamarin.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Check `label.Title = Encoding.UTF8.GetString("Álbum")` .

Comment: @MidhunMP Encoding.UTF8.GetString("Álbum") only accepts a byte array as parameter, so I used:
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Álbum");
    var stringEncoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 

But still no sucess, now the app shows weird characters/symbols where should be an accent.

Comment: @CL. when running that sqL: "near "0": syntax error"